# Show ActiveAdmin navigation bar on a member_action

Tags: navigation, activeadmin

I am attempting to create a member_action in ActiveAdmin, and would like the navigation bar to appear in the usual place at the top of the page.

I've tried with a view in both .erb and .arb formats, and have tried explicitly rendering the application layout, but the nav bar never shows.

Here's the doc for what I'm trying to do:

http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#rendering_in_custom_actions

As a workaround, I'm going to register a new page and hide it from the menu, even though that's wrong from a resourceful POV.

Any suggestions on how to do this appropriately would be appreciated!

Comment: ... and I tried the following partial rendering approach, and it didn't work either: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/725#issuecomment-6282092

Comment: Post some code and write more info about Active Admin (which version etc).